# Disable logging for specific useragent in nginx conf

Tags: nginx

I want to disable logging for a specific useragent. This is a part of my current conf-file.

`if ($http_user_agent ~ (bingbot|AhrefsBot|DotBot|Exabot|Baiduspider|SemrushBot) ) {
    return 403;
}`

I've tried adding `access_log off;` but get the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] "access_log" directive is not allowed here

I'm assuming this is because I only have a server block. I need a location block also. I've tried the following code:

`location / {
   if ($http_user_agent ~ (bingbot|AhrefsBot|DotBot|Exabot|Baiduspider|SemrushBot) ) {
      return 403;
   }
}`

But I get the following error:

> duplicate location "/"

In my conf-file I already have this code:

`location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`
}

Can I combine the two location snippets into one? Or how do I proceed?

Comment: The `access_log` directive includes an `if=condition` which can be controlled by a `map`. There's an example [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to also return 403 if condition=true?

Comment: Yes. Use: `if ($condition) { return 403; }`

Comment: Thanks! It's working! However, I just noticed that access_log now only includes robots. I need to negate the condition so that access_log exclude robots. Is there a way to negate condition for access_log? I've tried if!=condition - but I get error...

Comment: No. Negate the `map` and use `if ($condition = 0) { return 403; }`. (*assuming you're using `1` and `0` in your `map`*)

Comment: Thanks Richard! It's working now.

Answer (score 2):

As your question indicates, the `access_log` directive cannot be used within an `if` block unless enclosed within a `location`. However, the `access_log` directive does include an `if=condition` which can be controlled by a `map`. There is an example at the end of [this section](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) of the manual.

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $goodagent {
    default                                                    1;
    ~(bingbot|AhrefsBot|DotBot|Exabot|Baiduspider|SemrushBot)  0;
}    

server {
    access_log ... if=$goodagent;

    if ($goodagent = 0) { return 403; }

    ...
}
```

The `map` directive must be placed outside of the `server` block. The `access_log` statement can be placed inside or outside the `server` block depending on whether it applies to all `server` blocks or just one.

Answer (score 0):

At the `http` level declare a `map` like so.

```
map $http_user_agent $ignore_status_checks {
    default                 0;
    "~Pingdom.*"            1;
    "~*\(StatusCake\)"      1;
    "~*mod_pagespeed*"      1;
    "~*NodePing*"           1;
}
```

Then in your `server`'s `location` block add:

```
if ($ignore_status_checks) {
    access_log      off;
}
```

This will turn off the `access_log` for anything returns a `1` in the `map`. Of course, you can do want ever you want in the `if`.

Comment: @RichardSmith you are 100% correct. I missed a few words in my attempt to answer prior to running to a meeting. I have updated my answer to reflect that and upvoted yours as I forgot all about the if on the access_log.